# Jquery Sortable: Undefined Index to update database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm currently doing a school project which is due end of January '16. I am still new with jQuery thus, I really need some help in solving this problem of mine. 
With reference to [this](http://www.simonbattersby.com/blog/drag-and-drop-with-jquery-ui/), I tried and the sortable works however, the problem now is serializing it to update the database.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#sortable").sortable({
                opacity: 0.6,
                cursor: 'move',
                update: function () {
                    $('#changeMessage').html('Changes not saved');
                    $('#changeMessage').css("color", "red");
                }

            });

        });

        function saveDisplayOrder()
        {
            var order = $("#sortable").sortable("serialize");
            $('#changeMessage').html('Saving changes..');
            $.post("update_displayorder.php", order, function (theResponse) {
                $("#changeMessage").html(theResponse);
                $('#changeMessage').css("color", "green");
            });
        }

    </script>
```

PHP Codes

```
<?php
                    while ($item = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                        ?>
                        <tr data-role="list-divider">
                            <td id="ID_<?php echo $item['idQuestions'] ?>" ><?php echo $item['Question'] ?>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
<input type="button" onclick="return saveDisplayOrder()" value="Save Order" />
```

update_displayorder.php:

```
$theID = $_POST['ID'];
$counter = 1;

  foreach ($theID as $recordValue) {
  $query = "UPDATE questions SET displayOrder = '$counter'
          WHERE idQuestions = " . intval($recordValue);
  $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
  $counter ++;
  }

echo 'Changes saved';
```

The colours and words changes accordingly when sorting and upon clicking on the button. However, it does not update order in database as ID is an undefined index.

> Notice: Undefined index: ID in C:\xampp\htdocs\FYP\update_displayorder.php

I wonder what I did wrong as I followed exactly to the instructions

Comment: You don't need to change the order in the database, just in the jquery / html

Comment: the tutorial you link to sorting `<li>`. You have your `id` on a `<td>`. Are you actually sorting `<td>`s or the parent `<tr>`s?

Comment: your POST data is not in key value pair. Thus you can't access it as `$_POST['ID']`. Try `$theID = file_get_contents('php://input');`

Comment: @Sean I'm sorting the `<tr>`. It remained the same even after `<li>` is being used.. `<li id="ID_<?php echo $item['idQuestions'] ?>"><?php echo $item['Question'] ?></li>`